# PHP Input without associated label

Tags: php, html, forms, input, label

I have a Login form in my website which its inputs don't have associated labels, but for Accessibility reasons, they should have as it says here: https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/forms/labels/

Is there any way to avoid this or to have them hidden?

**Here is the code:**

```html
<fieldset id='clogin'>
<legend>Login</legend>

<div class='input-group'>
 <span class='input-group-addon'><i class='fa fa-user'></i></span>
    <input id='username' type='text' class='form-control' name='login' value='' placeholder='Username' required='' autofocus=''>
</div>

<div class='input-group'>
 <span class='input-group-addon'><i class='fa fa-lock'></i></span>
 <input id='password' type='password' class='form-control' name='password' placeholder='Password' required=''>
</div>

<button type='submit' class='btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block'>Login</button><br style='clear: both;'>

</fieldset>
```

Comment: As @B.Desai has mentioned, you simply don't use `<label></label>` tags. Just remove the tags completely from your code.

Comment: @B.Desai — How are people supposed to know what to type in the field without a label? (Keep in mind that placeholders disappear when you give the input focus, and screen readers tend not to read out placeholders)? The accessibility guidelines are there for a reason. Labels are compulsory. Don't tell people to ignore them.

Comment: "Is there any way to avoid this or to have them hidden?" — There is a **huge** section **in the document you linked to** on that subject. Keep reading past the first few paragraphs.

Comment: Thank you for confirming @Quentin. I have used the visuallyhidden approach from the link to hide them visually.

Answer (score -1):

In a UX point of view, placeholders only are not the right way to display input, because when you start typing something, you've got to remember the label.

However if you want to hide the labels, just add `display: none`

in your html file

```
<label for="input" class="hide">input</label>
```

in your css file

```
.hide
  {
    display:none;
  }
```

Comment: This is terrible advice. If they are `display: none` then people can't see them and screen readers won't read them out. You might as well not have them there at all for all the good they'll be.

Comment: You're right,  it's useless, and cannot be used for accessibility. This should answer better to your question :

http://webaim.org/techniques/css/invisiblecontent/